# R tibbles not printing correctly in VS Code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, tibble

I would like to use R tibbles in VS code but am seeing odd character formatting in tibble-output.

Take the `penguins` dataset from the `palmgerpenguins` package. The raw .csv looks like this:

```
"","species","island","bill_length_mm","bill_depth_mm","flipper_length_mm","body_mass_g","sex","year"
"1","Adelie","Torgersen",39.1,18.7,181,3750,"male",2007
"2","Adelie","Torgersen",39.5,17.4,186,3800,"female",2007
"3","Adelie","Torgersen",40.3,18,195,3250,"female",2007
"4","Adelie","Torgersen",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2007
"5","Adelie","Torgersen",36.7,19.3,193,3450,"female",2007
"6","Adelie","Torgersen",39.3,20.6,190,3650,"male",2007
```

When using R with VS Code, the output looks likes this:

```r
library(palmerpenguins)

head(penguins)

# A tibble: 6 Ã— 8
  species island    bill_length_mm bill_depth_mm flipper_lâ€¦Â¹ body_â€¦Â² sex    year
  <fct>   <fct>              <dbl>         <dbl>       <int>   <int> <fct> <int>
1 Adelie  Torgersen           39.1          18.7         181    3750 male   2007
2 Adelie  Torgersen           39.5          17.4         186    3800 femaâ€¦  2007
3 Adelie  Torgersen           40.3          18           195    3250 femaâ€¦  2007
4 Adelie  Torgersen           NA            NA            NA      NA NA     2007
5 Adelie  Torgersen           36.7          19.3         193    3450 femaâ€¦  2007
6 Adelie  Torgersen           39.3          20.6         190    3650 male   2007
# â€¦ with abbreviated variable names Â¹â€‹flipper_length_mm, Â²â€‹body_mass_g
```

This issue is only present on my work computer. My personal computer prints the tibble in VS code with the correct formatting.

I suspect the issue revolves around character encoding but I'm not sure what setting needs to be changed. My encoding settings in VS code are shown below. Any guidance on what features would need to be changed is much appreciated.

[image: encoding settings in VS code]

Comment: what does `head(penguins)` look like? Or what does the input data look like?

Comment: I have updated the question - please let me know if any other info would be helpful.

Comment: Try: `penguins[] <- lapply(penguins, function(x) if (is.character(x)) Encoding<-(x, 'UTF-8') else x)`

Comment: @TarJae that code produced an unexpected ',' error for me so I altered it slightly to `penguins[] <- lapply(penguins, function(x) if (is.character(x)) Encoding(x) <- "UTF-8" else x)`. Running `head(penguins)` after this produces the same character-formatting issues.

Comment: How does it look if you run the code in a plain R console started outside of VS Code? (I'm wondering if this is an issue with VS Code or with R itself.)

Comment: That's interesting - I tried running the above code in the R GUI and it produces the same character formatting issues. When I run the code in RStudio, the tibble prints normally. 

As I mentioned, this only occurs on my work computer - I'm wondering if admins changed some encoding feature in my Windows OS.

Comment: @JoshPersi It might be worth running these commands in both the R GUI and in RStudio to see if any of them produce different results: `Sys.getlocale()`; `Sys.getenv("LANG")`; `Sys.getenv("LANGUAGE")`.

Comment: The output is the same between the R GUI and RStudio
`Sys.getlocale()` produces `"LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8"`, `Sys.getenv("LANG")` produces `""`, and `Sys.getenv("LANGUAGE")` produces `""`

Comment: @JoshPersi In that case I'm not sure what to try next I'm afraid. If you don't get any answers here it may be worth opening an issue at the tibble repo: https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues